# How can I pass the results of get-childitem into a command?

Tags: powershell

I have several directories, subdirectories, etc in a directory structure and some of them will have various matching files.  e.g. if **X.config.default** exists in a directory it will also have a corresponding **X.config.build**

```
c:\Stuff\dir1
web.config.default
web.config.build

c:\Stuff\dir2
app.config.default
app.config.build

c:\Stuff\dir2\sub2
foo.config.default
foo.config.build
bar.config.default
bar.config.build
```

This will display all file names matching *.config.default and their corresponding directory

```
get-childitem -Recurse *.* -Filter *.config.default | Select Name, Directory
```

But instead of displaying the files and their path, I want to do something for each "match". In this case I want to call a program called **ctt** and send it three arguments.  ctt is called as follows:

```
ctt s:<source file> t:<transform file> d:<destination file>
```

Assume the first match is called `fubar` in directory `c:\Stuff\dir1`, the ctt command executed should look like:

```
ctt s:c:\Stuff\dir1\fubar.config.default t:c:\Stuff\dir1\fubar.config.build d:c:\Stuff\dir1\fubar.config pw
```

I'm guessing there are a few ways of doing this.  Piping `get-childitem` results into a command, or sending them to some sort of collection on which I can do a `foreach` loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways of approaching this. If you're on an older version of PowerShell, you'd most likely just use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\Stuff\* -Recurse -Filter *.config.default | 
  ForEach-Object -Process {
    $BuildName = $PSItem.Name.Split('.')[0] ### Get just the "fubar" part.
    ctt s:"$($PSItem.FullName)" t:"$($PSItem.Directory.FullName)\$BuildName.config.build" d:"$($PSItem.Directory.FullName).config" pw
  }
```

On newer versions of PowerShell, starting with 4.0, you can use the `ForEach()` method syntax.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26489.powershell-4-0-where-and-foreach-method-syntax.aspx

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path c:\Stuff\* -Recurse -Filter *.config.default).ForEach({ 
  $BuildName = $PSItem.Name.Split('.')[0] ### Get just the "fubar" part.
  ctt s:"$($PSItem.FullName)" t:"$($PSItem.Directory.FullName)\$BuildName.config.build" d:"$($PSItem.Directory.FullName).config" pw
}
```

Comment: @mklement0 how could you do this for newer versions?  Just curious

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit I updated the answer with your request.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Also worth mentioning that the `.ForEach()` method and its sibling, `.Where()`, aren't just syntax alternatives, but significantly faster than their cmdlet counterparts (compare `Measure-Command { 1..100000 | ForEach-Object { $_ } | out-null } | % TotalSeconds` to `Measure-Command { (1..100000).ForEach({ $_ }) | out-null } | % TotalSeconds`); also, they offer [additional features](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/).